# What is the minimum amount of boilerplate for negotiating content in Django?

Tags: python, django

In a Django application, I have more than a handful of views which return JSON, with an invocation similar to:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(content), mimetype="application/json")
```

I want to start creating views that return either HTML or JSON depending on the `Accept` headers from the request. Possibly other types, too, but those are the main ones. I also want to get multiple URLs routed to this view; the file extensions ".html" and ".json" help tell clients which types they should `Accept` when making their request, and I want to avoid the "?format=json" antipattern.

What's the correct, blessed way to do this in Django with a minimum of boilerplate or repeated code?

(Edit: Rephrase in order to better follow SO's community guidelines.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a [class-based view mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#more-than-just-html) (django 1.3+) is the easiest way to do this. All your views would inherit from a base class that contains logic to respond with the appropriate content.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may not be seeing your big picture here but this is what I would do:

Have a html template that you render when html is requested and keep your `json.dumps(content)` for when json is requested. Seems to be obvious but I thought i should mention it anyway.

Set your URLs to send you `"json"` or `'html'`. :

```
(r'^some/path/(?P<url_path>.*)\.(?P<extension>html|json)$', 'some.redirect.view'),
(r'^/(?P<extension>html|json)/AppName', include(MyApp)),
# etc etc
```

and your view:

```
def myRedirectView(request, url_path, extension):

    view, args, kwargs = resolve("/" + extension + "/" + urlPath)
    kwargs['request'] = request

    return view(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know this is a bit vague because I haven't fully thought it through but its where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed this by creating a generic view class, based on Django's own generic.View class, that defines a decorator 'accept_types'.  This modifies the view to which it is applied so that it returns None if the indicated content-type is not in the Accept header.  Then, the get() method (which is called by the generic.View dispatcher) looks like this:

```
def get(self, request):
    self.request = request      # For clarity: generic.View does this anyway
    resultdata = { 'result': data, etc. }
    return (
        self.render_uri_list(resultdata) or
        self.render_html(resultdata) or 
        self.error(self.error406values())
        )
```

The actual view renderers are decorated thus:

```
@ContentNegotiationView.accept_types(["text/uri-list"])
def render_uri_list(self, resultdata):
    resp = HttpResponse(status=200, content_type="text/uri-list")
    # use resp.write(...) to assemble rendered response body
    return resp

@ContentNegotiationView.accept_types(["text/html", "application/html", "default_type"])
def render_html(self, resultdata):
    template = loader.get_template('rovserver_home.html')
    context  = RequestContext(self.request, resultdata)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The (one-off) generic view class that declares the decorator looks like this:

```
class ContentNegotiationView(generic.View):
    """
    Generic view class with content negotiation decorators and generic error value methods

    Note: generic.View dispatcher assigns HTTPRequest object to self.request. 
    """

    @staticmethod
    def accept_types(types):
        """
        Decorator to use associated function to render the indicated content types 
        """
        def decorator(func):
            def guard(self, values):
                accept_header = self.request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT',"default_type")
                accept_types  = [ a.split(';')[0].strip().lower() 
                                  for a in accept_header.split(',') ]
                for t in types:
                    if t in accept_types:
                        return func(self, values)
                return None
            return guard
        return decorator
```

(The parameter handling in the decorator should be generalized - this code works, but is still in development as I write this.  The actual code is in GitHub at https://github.com/wf4ever/ro-manager/tree/develop/src/roverlay/rovweb/rovserver, but in due course should be separated to a separate package.  HTH.)